# Use dash '-' in object property name in C#

Tags: c#, json

In C# I am passing an object to a function. I need to add a property in object that contains dash "-" in it. How can I pass this dashed property in object?

```
SendPushNotificationByAPNS(
device.RegisterId,
new
{
    aps = new
    {
        badge = 0
        alert = new
        {
            title = notificationTitle,
            body = notificationBody,
            sound = "default"
        },
        mutable-content = 1 <-- I need to add this but C# doesn't allow
    },
    entityId = entityId,
    entityType = entityType
});
```

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Why do you need a `-` in a property name?

Comment: If you are using JSON.Net you can define a custom formatter.

Comment: A custom formatter is probably overkill. It's easy enough to just [add an attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5771591/542251).

Comment: @KevinAnderson That makes no sense for an identifier such as a variable's name. You don't pass the variable's name but its value.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to name properties in C# in the same way as in JSON format, you have to create a class with all properties that you need with regard to C# naming conventions.

Then you can add `[JsonProperty("mutable-content")]` attribute with name of the field that you expected to see in a JSON file.

After your applicaiton will make request to another source it will be automatically serialized.